# ZF2 - Database transactions with updating multiple tables

Tags: database, transactions, zend-framework2

I want to use ZF2 db transaction to update multiple tables.
Normally I do transaction by something like this for a single table:

```
 $connection = null;
 try {
        $connection = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection();
        $connection->beginTransaction();
        $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
        $connection->commit();
     }
  catch (Exception $e) {
       if ($connection instanceof \Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ConnectionInterface) {
          $connection->rollback();
       }
  }
```

Now I want to update two tables inside one transaction. In ZF1 I did this by creating a instance of table2 class and calling its appropriate method inside same transaction. But since I don't know the method to call another model class inside a model, I cannot do as ZF1. I need this for a simple task like adding new rows to a tbl_invoice and updating tbl_runno table's running number for invoices when entering a new bill(invoice).

Answer (score 3):

In your controller you can do:

```
$db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$con = $db->getDriver()->getConnection();
$con->beginTransaction();
try {
    //get tables and do sth
    $con->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $con->rollback();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DataMapper design pattern. Pattern TableGateway serves to project data to a single table.

- http://akrabat.com/development/objects-in-the-model-layer
- http://akrabat.com/php/objects-in-the-model-layer-part-2
- http://www.slideshare.net/aaronsaray/midwest-php-2013
- https://leanpub.com/zendframework2-en
  You can use something like this:

  ```
  namespace ScContent\Mapper;

  use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
  use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
  use Zend\Db\Sql\SqlInterface;
  use Zend\Db\Sql\PreparableSqlInterface;

  use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
  use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\ResultInterface;

  use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;
  use Zend\StdLib\Hydrator\HydratorInterface;

  abstract class AbstractDbMapper
  {
      /**
       * @var string
       */
      const JoinInner = Select::JOIN_INNER;

      /**
       * @var string
       */
      const JoinLeft = Select::JOIN_LEFT;

      /**
       * @var string
       */
      const JoinRight = Select::JOIN_RIGHT;

      /**
       * @var Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface
       */
      protected $_adapter;

      /**
       * @var Zend\Db\Sql\SqlInterface
       */
      protected $_sql;

      /**
       * @var Zend\Stdlib\HydratorInterface
       */
      protected $_hydrator;

      /**
       * @var array
       */
      protected $_tables = array();

      /**
       * @param Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface $adapter
       */
      public function setAdapter(AdapterInterface $adapter)
      {
          $this->_adapter = $adapter;
      }

      /**
       * @return Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface
       */
      public function getAdapter()
      {
          if(!$this->_adapter instanceof AdapterInterface) {
              throw new Exception('Adapter is not installed.');
          }
          return $this->_adapter;
      }

      /**
       * @param Zend\Db\Sql\SqlInterface $sql
       */
      public function setSql(SqlInterface $sql)
      {
          $this->_sql = $sql;
      }

      /**
       * @return Zend\Db\Sql\SqlInterface
       */
      public function getSql()
      {
          if(!$this->_sql instanceof SqlInterface) {
              $this->_sql = new Sql($this->getAdapter());
          }
          return $this->_sql;
      }

      /**
       * @param Zend\Stdlib\HydratorInterface $hydrator
       */
      public function setHydrator(HydratorInterface $hydrator)
      {
          $this->_hydrator = $hydrator;
      }

      /**
       * @return Zend\Stdlib\HydratorInterface
       */
      public function getHydrator()
      {
          if(!$this->_hydrator instanceof HydratorInterface) {
              $this->_hydrator = new ClassMethods();
          }
          return $this->_hydrator;
      }

      /**
       * @param string $alias
       * @param string $name
       */
      public function setTable($alias, $name)
      {
          $this->_tables[$alias] = $name;
      }

      /**
       * @param string $alias
       * @throws Exception
       * @return string
       */
      public function getTable($alias)
      {
          if(!array_key_exists($alias, $this->_tables)) {
              throw new Exception(sprintf("Unknown table alias '%s'.", $alias));
          }
          return $this->_tables[$alias];
      }

      /**
       * @return int|null|false
       */
      protected function lastInsertId()
      {
          return $this->adapter->getDriver()->getConnection()->getLastGeneratedValue();
      }

      /**
       * @param void
       * @return void
       */
      protected function beginTransaction()
      {
          $this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
      }

      /**
       * @param void
       * @return void
       */
      protected function commit()
      {
          $this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->commit();
      }

      /**
       * @return bool
       */
      protected function inTransaction()
      {
          return $this->getAdapter()->getDriver()
              ->getConnection()->getResource()->inTransaction();
      }

      /**
       * @param void
       * @return void
       */
      protected function rollBack()
      {
          $this->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->rollBack();
      }

      /**
       * @param Zend\Db\Sql\PreparableSqlInterface $sqlObject
       * @return Zend\Db\Adapter\ResultInterface
       */
      protected function execute(PreparableSqlInterface $sqlObject)
      {
          return $this->getSql()->prepareStatementForSqlObject($sqlObject)->execute();
      }

      /**
       * @param Zend\Db\Adapter\ResultInterface $source
       * @return array
       */
      protected function toArray(ResultInterface $source)
      {
          $result = array();
          foreach($source as $item) {
              $result[] = $item;
          }
          return $result;
      }

      /**
       *
       */
      protected function toString(SqlInterface $sqlObject)
      {
          return $this->getSql()->getSqlStringForSqlObject($sqlObject);
      }
  }
  ```

  Example of use:

  ```
  <?php  


  namespace ScContent\Mapper;

  use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;

  class ContentMapper extends AbstractDbMapper
  {
      /**
       * @var string
       */
      const ContentTableAlias = 'contentalias';

      /**
       * @var string
       */
      const UsersTableAlias = 'usersalias';

      /**
       * @param AdapterInterface $adapter
       */
      public function __construct(AdapterInterface $adapter) {
          $this->setAdapter($adapter);
      }

      /**
       * @var array
       */
      protected $_tables = array(
          self::ContentTableAlias => 'sc_content',
          self::UsersTableAlias   => 'sc_users'
      );

      /**
       * @param integer $id
       * @return null | array
       */
      public function findById($id)
      {
          $select = $this->getSql()->select()
              ->from(array('content' => $this->getTable(self::ContentTableAlias)))
              ->join(
                  array('users' => $this->getTable(self::UsersTableAlias)),
                  'content.author = users.user_id',
                  array('username'),
                  self::JoinInner
              )
              ->where(array('`content`.`id` = ?' => $id));
          return $this->execute($select)->current();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the Akrabat's links you given above, the approach is bit different(Entity, Mapper, Service 3 objects) to the sample code you supplied above. In ZfcUser module (https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser), they have used Akrabat's approach but with bit complexity. Do you think ZfcUser's method will work for me?

Comment: You must understand the difference between the mapper and the gateway. Mapper can return aggregates and collections, and each item in the collection - it is a separate object. Mapper ZfcBase returns a ResultSet, and that should do the standard gateway. If the flexibility afforded by the gateway you want, then you will approach and ZfcBase AbstractDbMapper.